# Pandas if statement across list of columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a DataFrame with several columns that are either 0's or 1's. For example:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame([[1,1,0], [0,0,0], [0,1,1], [0,1,0]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

I want to create a new column that is populated with the value 1 if any of the list of columns `['A', 'B', 'C']` is equal to 1.

I can do this as follows:

```
>>> df['Any']=0
>>> df['Any'][(df["A"] == 1) | (df["B"] == 1) | (df["C"] == 1)]=1
```

However, how can I can pass a list of columns, such as `Cols=['A', 'B', 'C']` and have a new field be populated with 1 if any of the columns in the list equals 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `any` method:

```
In [11]: df == 1
Out[11]:
       A      B      C
0   True   True  False
1  False  False  False
2  False   True   True
3  False   True  False

In [12]: (df == 1).any(1)
Out[12]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

You can pass in a subset of the columns:

```
In [13]: (df[['A', 'C']] == 1).any(1)
Out[13]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```